# What is Importance Value?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics

I am reading this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4224527/#b34) that talks about Principle Components analysis and Importance Values(IV) here [image: Photo]
Is this Importance Value a statistical concept? I could not find any information about it in Google.

Comment: It's something the authors came up with, but did not provided information on how it's calculated. I checked Wilsey 2005 which they cited, nothing..

Comment: @StupidWolf Oh, I see . Thank you very much!